# Count number of occurrences of two words in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to be able to find number of occurrences of two words in a string within a given range. Given two keywords and range, return number of occurrences keywords exist within given range. So for example having the following string (keywords are also included in the range):

```
input string:
    "on top on bottom on side Works this Magic door"

input filters: "on", "side", range: 6
```

(Range 6 means, that there can be at most four other words between those two we search)

```
output should be: 3
```

(since the match of "on" and "side" occurs 3 times.

example 2:

```
input string:
    "on top on bottom on side Works this Magic door"

input filters: "on", "side", range: 3

output should be: 1
```

I've tried this regex "`\bon\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}?side\b`"
however this does not return expected output. I'm not sure if "regex" is the right way to go.

Comment: This is one of the most confusing descriptions of a problem I've read. Can you please edit the question to make it very clear what the input is, what you're matching against, what the output is, and **how** the calculation is performed?

Comment: made edits, hopefully that helps. thanks

Comment: It's still confusing. What exactly is the meaning of range in this context, i.e. how does it affect the response? Also in your first example "on" occurs 3 times but "side" occurs just one time. Why is the output 3? So, to summarize you need to describe the exact requirements of your problem.

Comment: Range 6 means, that there can be at most four other words between those two we search?

Comment: yes. it means 6 words total including keywords (2)

Comment: Have you tried anything _besides_ regex? It might be easier to conceptualize; I think regex could handle your task if you use one of the look-ahead options (i.e. so that the terminating word `"side"` isn't part of the actual match and so isn't consumed by a match), but **a)** I'm not a regex expert so can't say for sure, and **b)** regex is hard enough to read and write that if not for the benefit of an expert, it's probably better to resort to more explicit code (e.g. brute force...maybe slower, but likely to be easier to write and maintain).

Comment: You should provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you have tried, with a precise description of what that code does and in what way that's different from what you want it to do. I feel that the question itself is easily understood based on what you've posted, but as stated now it's too broad to be useful on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is correct for range 8. Problem is overlapping matches, this can not be done in one search. You have to do something like this:

```
string s = "on top on bottom on side Works this Magic door";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\bon\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,4}side\b");
int output = 0;
int start = 0;
while (start < s.Length)
{
    Match m = r.Match(s, start);
    if (!m.Success) { break; }
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    output++;
    start = m.Index + 1;
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: ahh, so for any given range I would do -2

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            string input = "on top on bottom on side Works this Magic door";
            List<string> array = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

            int onIndex = array.IndexOf("on");
            int sideIndex = array.IndexOf("side");

            int results = sideIndex - onIndex - 1;
```